# how can i execute python commands(?) in python script?

Tags: python, python-3.x

i wonder how to import python console in my python script.
If there are a script named script1.py, that taking string input from console.
What i want to do is that, if i give string input "print(5)" to the script1.py,
than it executes the print(5) (which will give the 5 as result as we use the python console).

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/custominterp.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the python `eval()` function, as in https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval. That evaluates any input string as python code.

For instance:

```py
x = 1
eval('x+1')
2
```

Be careful with eval though; if the string to be evaluated comes from unprotected user input, it can do anything your own python code can do.

Comment: [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html?highlight=ast%20literal_eval#ast.literal_eval) is a safer choice exactly for the reason you mentioned.

Comment: @b_c No, literal_eval can't work with operators. It is safe because it is very simple.

Comment: @EkremDİNÇEL you're right, I forgot about that. I still don't agree with `eval` being the correct choice here though, _especially_ with the goal of executing arbitrary strings submitted through a console.

Comment: @b_c for sure it is not safe. You shouldn't use it in real application.

Comment: Well, if OP is trying to create a virtual python console for instance, like a Jupyter notebook sort of thing, then this would be fine -- the user is basically typing python code into some UI and the user is responsible for the result. It's just important to be aware of the power `eval()` brings.

Comment: If the goal is to create a virtual console, OP would be better served using something like [`cmd`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmd.html#cmd.Cmd) or [`cmd2`](https://github.com/python-cmd2/cmd2) to create a proper console interface as opposed to kludging something together with `eval`. I'd argue that `eval` is rarely the right option - there's almost always a better way to do it.

Comment: @GaryO I think using python interpreter as a subprocess for your case is better. ``eval`` can manipulate your application, even if you pass globals as empty.